# "clear" an ArrayList then use it again without terminating the program

Tags: java, list, arraylist

**What I want to happen**

input = a,b,c,d

output = a,b,c,d

input (without terminating program) = e,f,g,h

output = e,f,g,h

**What is happening**

input = a,b,c,d

output = a,b,c,d

input (without terminating program) = e,f,g,h

output = "empty"

**Code**

Outside the main

```
public static ArrayList<String> alpha = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In a different method

```
alpha.add("string"); //string contains an element which is changed after each loop
```

In the main, after printing the result

```
alpha.clear();
alpha = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then I ask the user if they want to enter a different text and that's when it returns an empty list. Also note, when I don't include the .clear it will just repeat the old output.

EDIT:

```
public static void startDFA(List<String> listDFA){

   for (index = 0; index<size; index++){
      String currString = listDFA.get(index);
      int sizeCurrString = currString.length();

      if (currString.indexOf('{') != -1 || currString.indexOf('}') != -1 ){
          //System.out.println("curly");
          curly++;
      }
      if (curly <= 2){
          Q.add(currString);
      }
      if (curly > 2 && curly <5){
          sigma.add(currString);
      }
      //System.out.println(index);
      //System.out.println(listDFA.get(index));
   }
   printVal();
}

public static void printVal(){
  System.out.println("The states (Q) are: ");
  System.out.println(Q);
  System.out.println("The elements (Sigma) are: ");
  System.out.println(sigma);
}

public static void main(String[] args){                             // MAIN
  boolean recur = true; 
  while (recur){                                                    //Reiterates question
       System.out.println("Start? 'y' or 'n'");                       //Ask user to start program
       Scanner reply = new Scanner(System.in);
       String strRep = reply.nextLine();

       if (strRep.compareTo("y")==0){
           System.out.println("Started");
           System.out.println("Please enter a encoded DFA: ");        //Ask user for DFA
           String DFA = reply.nextLine();
           System.out.println("You've entered: " + DFA );             //Reiterates string user inputed
        List<String> listDFA = Arrays.asList(DFA.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        size = listDFA.size();
        startDFA(listDFA);
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("End of program.");
        recur = false;
     }  
  }   
}
```

**Screenshots**
[Part1](https://gyazo.com/5b228eb95f8ef04237f23e344def3743), [Part2](https://gyazo.com/54e61420f219a42689e0f89ad36fc8ab), and [Part3](https://gyazo.com/a89ca41ed58ed11a60b0190f6a96f355)

Comment: Can you put more of your code? I think you are not inserting values to the list in the 2nd time when you are getting input.

Comment: Also I don't know if there are other dynamically sized way of storing data, but the size of string can vary

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha updated the post, all the main has is the call for startDFA and asks for user prompts

Comment: @Nate the stuff you have omitted is where the problem is.

Comment: @Nate Calling `x.clear()` before you assign a new ArrayList to x is redundant. After both you'd have an empty list in x (with a subtle difference that doesn't matter here).

Comment: @Nate If your inputs are `a,b,c,d` or `e,f,g,h`: how come you are counting curly brackets? How are the strings in listDFA related to these inputs (if at all)?

Comment: @How are `Q`, `sigma` and `size` declared and how are they used? What is the relation of `alpha` to these lists?

Comment: Please add the content of your main method. The code you have provided so far is not helping or even related to your question. From my best guess it appears you possibly have just mixed up assigning to or printing from the right lists.

Comment: @JavaDevil updated the code with the main now, what boggles me is that it works for the first input then just does nothing for the second.

Comment: @laune the alpha example was just me trying to simplify my example, sorry about the confusion. As for the curly braces, they just determine which method I use depending on the number of curly braces that exist. Q and sigma are both arraylist while size is an integer

Comment: alpha.clear();

better if you commented this line

//alpha = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @Nate "in the main, after printing the result...alpha.clear();..." where is that? Your code does not show that. Moreover where do you declare size and index? Where are Q and Sigma declared? It would help if you could post more relevant code

Comment: @AngeloOparah oops, I've changed the code since I posted and when I pasted it in it was removed to test some things out. Size is in the main which is equal to the size of listDFA, as for index, it's starts at 0. and both Q and sigma are declared as arraylist outside of the main, better explained with these screenshots: [Part1](https://gyazo.com/5b228eb95f8ef04237f23e344def3743), [Part2](https://gyazo.com/54e61420f219a42689e0f89ad36fc8ab), and [Part3](https://gyazo.com/a89ca41ed58ed11a60b0190f6a96f355)

Comment: Don't use screenshots, but above all, *don't use links*. They'll be gone in a while, making this exercise useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure about your **if clause** as your inputs are a,b,c,d or e,f,g,h and you are looking for braces *(* & *)*. One issue i see in your code is you increment your **curly** variable count and it is working fine at first run because when you first time run your application **curly = 0**. But after you are done with first run your curly will be greater than zero or can say to the maximum value possible for first run case. You should reset curly = 0 either in start of startDFA method outside for loop like described below or else set curly = 0 in your main method before calling startDFA. Apart from this you also require to clear your Q, sigma, translation, start & finish arraylist if required along with curly. Best place is to do all this resetting and clearing is inside startDFA method outside for loop.

```
public static void startDFA(List<String> listDFA){
   curly = 0
   for (index = 0; index<size; index++){

   }
}
```

Comment: This was it, never thought about the curly count. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just declaring a lot of static variables is bad coding style - you saw what happens. Declare a class, make the variables carrying the relevant info into fields (here: 2 lists). Declare other variables in the innermost reach (here: curly). Don't declare useless variables (here: size, sizeCurrString). Use the compact for of the for statement.

```
public class Curly {
    private List<String> q = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> sigma = new ArrayList<>();

    public void startDFA( List<String> listDFA){
        int curly = 0;
        for( String curr: listDFA ){
            if( curr.indexOf('{') != -1 ||
                curr.indexOf('}') != -1 ){
                curly++;
            } // maybe: else 
            if (curly <= 2){
                q.add(curr);
            } else if( curly <5 ){
                sigma.add(curr);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printVal(){
        System.out.println("The states (Q) are: ");
        System.out.println(q);
        System.out.println("The elements (Sigma) are: ");
        System.out.println(sigma);
    }
}
```

And in main you do:

```
    Curly curly = new Curly();
    curly.startDFA( listDFA );
    curly.printVal();
```

Add more methods (e.g. `List<String> getQ`) if the program needs to grow. *Avoid static*.